# Displaying ONLY hours and Minutes in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, time

Using Excel 2010.

I'm not an Excel neophyte as I've been using is since the late '80s, but haven't had to do this before.

I'm building an agenda for a meeting where I want to display the start time and end time for each agenda item.

As they are all different and people are rearranging the schedule, I want to put the duration in a hidden field and have the END time be the START time plus DURATION.

The problem is that I keep getting the mm/dd/yyy displayed as well as AM/PM even though I'm formatting the cells as `hhmm` to get a 24 hour clock.

Comment: How are you adding the duration?  What formula are you using?  Could you mock up some data to help us visualize what you want?

Comment: Some diagrams of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: Are you sure the data is an actual time/date in excel and not just a string.  Formatting it as a number you should get a number around 42,000.  If it doesn't format as a number its not truly a time/date.  Formatting as hhmm should work. formatting as [hh]mm would allow >24 hours to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

First format both **A1** and **C1** with this format:

"[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM"

In **A1** enter the date/time for meeting start.
In **B1** enter the duration in **minutes**
In **C1** enter the formula:

```
=A1+TIME(0,B1,0)
```

For example:

[image]